# Where was the term "coinbase" first coined, who first used it?

Tags: terminology, coinbase-transaction, history, satoshi-nakamoto, whitepaper

The white paper doesn't mention the term "coinbase" (in reference to the reward transaction).

I see the [first version of the software `main.cpp`](https://github.com/blaesus/bitcoin-0.0.1/blob/254bc03fa93ad4eb40e9add39e19d35277440456/src/main.cpp#L1167C5-L1172C67) does:

```
    // First transaction must be coinbase, the rest must not be
    if (vtx.empty() || !vtx[0].IsCoinBase())
        return error("CheckBlock() : first tx is not coinbase");
    for (int i = 1; i < vtx.size(); i++)
        if (vtx[i].IsCoinBase())
            return error("CheckBlock() : more than one coinbase");
...
```

Did the term orginate in the Satoshi's code?
Who first used the term on a forum, mailing list or other public venue?

I'm looking to trace back to the "original specification" of the coinbase transaction, if there is one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term "coinbase" was most likely coined by Satoshi through the `IsCoinbase` method of the `CTransaction` class. It was both part of the first publicly distributed version of the source code and of the (allegedly) [privately shared early versions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=382374) of it.

Answer (score 0):

> Who first used the term on a forum, mailing list or other public venue?

The earliest post I could find mentioning "coinbase" on bitcoin talk was on June 21, 2010 by user Laszlo:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=198.msg1640#msg1640

> I'm looking to trace back to the "original specification" of the
> coinbase transaction, if there is one.

As alluded to by Antoine Poinsot, it seems the original specification is the [`isCoinBase` method of a `CTransaction` object](https://github.com/blaesus/bitcoin-0.0.1/blob/254bc03fa93ad4eb40e9add39e19d35277440456/src/main.h#L437), as well as its [`checkTransaction`](https://github.com/blaesus/bitcoin-0.0.1/blob/254bc03fa93ad4eb40e9add39e19d35277440456/src/main.h#L442C15-L442C15) method:

```cpp
class CTransaction
{
public:
    int nVersion;
    vector<CTxIn> vin;
    ...
    bool IsCoinBase() const
    {
        return (vin.size() == 1 && vin[0].prevout.IsNull());
    }
    ...

    bool CheckTransaction() const
    {
        ...
        if (IsCoinBase())
            {
                if (vin[0].scriptSig.size() < 2 || vin[0].scriptSig.size() > 100)
                    return error("CTransaction::CheckTransaction() : coinbase script size");
            }
        ...
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Which I take to mean "The coinbase transaction shall be a standard transaction with exactly one null input transaction where the input scriptSig size is in the range 2 to 100 bytes."

Here, "null" is [defined as a `COutPoint` object with hash==0 and n==-1](https://github.com/blaesus/bitcoin-0.0.1/blob/254bc03fa93ad4eb40e9add39e19d35277440456/src/main.h#L157):

```cpp
class COutPoint
{
public:
    uint256 hash;
    unsigned int n;
    ...
    bool IsNull() const { return (hash == 0 && n == -1); }
    ...
}
```